# TDD strategy when implementing a multi-stage process?

Tags: tdd

At the moment I'm developing a piece of code which first gathers sentences from a set of documents, then tokenises these, then uses the results to analyse recurring frequencies of token sequences, including case variations (upper case/lower case/leading cap/other), then prints out the results.

Now I want to introduce two more stages before printing out the results:
1. firstly, removing "stop words" (i.e. words or short sequences the frequency of which can never be of interest, such as, in English, "the", "of the", "of which", etc.) - these stop words/"stop sequences" to be taken from a database table
2. secondly, bringing up a dialog enabling the user to identify sequences of new stop words, which would then remove the token sequences involved and also add the sequence in question to the database table.

The thing is, this is a multi-stage process, and I'm just wondering what TDD experts do faced with a situation like this: do I create a new test method for each individual stage...?  The problem being that each individual stage requires the use of "live memory data" from the previous stage: another possibility could be to somehow serialise this data and then deserialise it when testing for the next stage... but then this would involve the app code doing things which were of benefit only for the testing code, i.e. it would mean tweaking ("distorting"?) the app code for the benefit of the testing code, which seems wrong in principle...

Also, if anyone can point me in the direction of a book or site which helps TDD newbs like myself go to "the next level" I would be very grateful.

***later***

To the person who marked this as "favorite": I've now got hold of a book called "Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests", which is well-reviewed and appears to be for someone wanting to move from beginner to intermediate.  First impressions good.

Any views on this book by experts also welcome, of course...

Comment: Just to be clear, you already have tests for the existing stages of the process and your question is about the new stages you are introducing?

Comment: I've just developed the existing 2 stages in a single functional test... I'm now wondering how a multi-stage process is broken down, in practice, by experienced TDD people... so as a first step I've put these 2 stages into separate methods (I'm using Jython, and this is all happening in a SwingWorker).  But just making a method for a given stage still leaves the question of creating the **pre-conditions** for each method to be tested... Hope this makes sense....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the face of it, you seem to be building a pipeline.  From what I can tell, you're currently implementing all of it within a single class, which stores both the data that's being worked on and implements the methods that do the processing.  One approach that you could take would be to break down the problem into smaller chunks.  Rather than having a single class, you have a class for each stage of the pipeline and another class for orchestrating the process which is responsible for plugging the stages together in the correct order.

So, scanning through what you've described, you appear to have the following processors:

- DocumentReader (reads documents from somewhere into in memory document)
- SentenceExtractor (document/list of documents in, list of sentences out)
- 1 or more SentenceAnalysers (sentences in, statistics out), you might want to break this down depending on the type of analysis and how complex it is.
- StopWordExtractor (StopWordProvider and sentences in, sentences out)

There are additional supporting classes that would be needed, to support writing of new stopwords to the database and depending on how the stopwordprovider was implemented keeping it in sync as the user selects new ones.

Essentially, what I'm saying is that you appear to be doing too much in a single location.  If you're *really* happy that the code as you've described it is a single unit, then there is nothing wrong with you testing it all in one place, but then your inputs will be your starting documents/sentences and your outputs will be the end of the process.  If you agree with me that really, there are several distinct components involved in the process that could change independently, then I would suggest breaking the process down into smaller classes and testing that those perform as expected for given sets of inputs/outputs...

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, you've put it very clearly.  A "pipeline"... that term sums it up perfectly.  This morning I have been scratching my head and slowly working it out... maybe it's a bit obvious when you think about it (having been given the answer!).  It implies an "orchestrating" class as you say... so more work... I suppose that's the price to pay for a more robust solution.